# Почему при вставке ошибка ORA-02291: integrity constraint parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, переменные

Не получается вставить данные. В переменные значение попадают, но при попытке вставить в таблицу появляется ошибка:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (YOZHIK.Oblad_fk2) violated - parent key not found

Если же ввести вручную значения из запросов, то все проходит без проблем:

```
DECLARE
  Count_Tip   number;
  Count_Firm  number;
  Count_Model number;

  BEGIN

    SELECT Max(ID) into Count_Tip FROM "Tip" ;
    SELECT Max(ID) into Count_Firm FROM "Firm" ;
    SELECT Max(ID) into Count_Model FROM "Model";
    
  insert into "Oblad"("ID_Tip","ID_Firm","ID_Model","Polomka") Values
      (
        Count_Tip,
        Count_Model,
        Count_Firm,
        'test4'
      );
END;
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Вы вставляете в поля, по порядку: "ID_Tip","ID_Firm","ID_Model", А переменные при этом ставите в другом порядке: Count_Tip,
        Count_Model,
        Count_Firm

Comment: И кстати переменные и процедура тут как бы и не нужны. `insert into ... select (select max(id) from tip), (select max()...), (select ...), 'test4' from DUAL` отлично справится

Comment: Действительно, вот оно что), спасибо.
Процедура нужна, я просто упростил  её, я заношу данные в 3 таблицы (тип, модель, фирма) и через процедуру заношу ид в Облад.
Спасибо, так и знал что что-то упустил по невнимательности

Comment: А откуда у вас там ID берется, select max(id) не совсем безопасно, он может оказаться не тем, что вы вставили. Обычно при вставке используются секвенсы, стоит брать из них currVal после вставки

Comment: ID в таблицы вставляется BI тригерром из секвенса,
следовательно при вставке нового значения в таблицу, ID у него будет максимальный.

Comment: @Mike всё равно прав, это небезопасно. Подумайте, нельзя ли переписать на returning, тем более если insert в остальные таблицы в той же процедуре.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579731/parent-key-not-found-oracle#comment769419_579731):

> ID в таблицы вставляется BI тригерром из секвенса, следовательно при вставке нового значения в таблицу, ID у него будет максимальный.

Тут некоторое заблуждение, `MAX(id)` вернёт действительно максимальное значение, только возможно не то, которое ожидается.

Попробуем простой пример:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key);

set autoprint on
var newid number
begin
    insert into t1 values (1);
    select max (id) into :newid from t1;
end;
/
```

Вроде сомнений нет, вернёт `newid=1`, но результат:

```
NEWID
-
2
```

Причина проста, в другой сессии выполнил тот же блок с `id=2` и зафиксировал  изменение.

Вот так правильно получить `id` после вставки:

```
var newid number
begin
    insert into t1 values (1) 
    returning id into :newid;
end;
/
NEWID
-
1
```